# Torus with one disk attached inside

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I was working in some problems and I found this answer. [Homology of Torus with two discs glued on the inside](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224231/homology-of-torus-with-two-discs-glued-on-the-inside) As the answer states, a torus with two disks attached inside is homotopically equivalent to $S^{1}\lor S^{2} \lor S^{2} $, my question is, a torus with just one disk attached inside would be homotopically equivalent to $S^{1}\lor S^{2}$ ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the disk is attached in the same way as in the link, then yes, and the argument is analogous to the answer of the linked question.